# Using <h:form> breaks my JSF page until I make a ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf, facelets

I am using PrimeFaces and the newest jsf stuff.

```
<p:dataGrid var="terms" value="#{coursePlanSandbox.preProcessedTerms}" columns="4" rows="20">
    <h:form style="margin:0px;">
        <div class="list-widget classDrop">
            <div class="list-head">
                <h3>#{coursePlanSandbox.termName(terms.term)}</h3>
                <div class="list-meta">
                    #{terms.term.startYear} 
                    <span class="pull-right" style="margin-top:-3px;">
                        #{terms.fToi(terms.scheduledUnits)} / 
                        <h:inputText styleClass="inputMaxUnits" value="#{terms.firstSession.maxUnits}" >
                            <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</p:dataGrid>
```

This is a snippet of my Facelets file. What happens is if I do a fresh run of the page, right click the Facelets file in NetBeans and click 'Run File' which refreshes the server I guess, the page stops loading after `<h:inputText>` and nothing else loads after that point. Even when I refresh the page, it stops loading after that point. If I enter a value in the `<h:inputText>` and it sends an ajax request to the server, if I then click refresh, the page loads everything else after that. Is it a bug with the server or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what it was, I was calling an object in my controller before it was made, breaking the page. And once the ajax call when thru, it called the class constructor and built the object. So thats why every refresh after that it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why using Run File... normally you run the JSF Project (or Debug it) and you don't need to run anything else when doing changes inside xhtml files nor java files (except when you are adding / modifying classes and functions prototypes). Run file is useful to run a class that contains main().

Comment: If I quit netbeans and shutdown all the servers and then restart everything back up it does the same thing.

Comment: Which server are you using with NetBeans?